# Calculate the product of distances for a line perpendicular to hyperbola

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Let us have a hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ and assume the normal at P meets the transverse (horizontal) axis $AA'$ in $G$ and the conjugate (vertical) axis $BB'$ in $g$. Assume CF be perpendicular to the normal from the center.

1. Find $\frac{PF \cdot PG}{CB^2}$
2. Find $PF \cdot Pg$

How can I solve the question in least amount of steps? 
My attempt:

I first formed the equation of the normal and then I found out the points where it cuts the conjugate and transverse axis. After finding these points I used distance formula to find the distance required and convert it in the form that the question asked. But its a long method and took lot of steps

[image]

Comment: Can you please show your current method of solving this question?

Comment: It's really long..basically we form the equation of normal and find the points g and G.using the points we find the distances and try to match them with the options given?

Comment: Have you drawn the graph?

Comment: Yeah. But the graph offers very little information. With out the points I don't not know how to proceed.

Comment: @LakshyaGupta I am really not sure as for what are these points so I'l be glad if you'll tell me since it isn't said what is AA' is it's focus's points? vertex? So tell me so I can help you.

Comment: AA' are the end points of the transverse axis or (a,0) and (-a,0)

Comment: I tried a simpler method. But it way to long and obvious.